# Need to encrypt specific columns values in ADF copy data activity?

Tags: encryption, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, copydataset

**What I do**
I am reading the CSV file from the Azure storage account and copying the same data to the Azure SQL database in a table. The CSV file contains PII information such as first name, last name, phone and email. The column mapping with the sink database is one to one.

**Want solution for:**
No issue, all data is properly copied. On top of that I want to encrypt the PII information. After encryption I will see only the encrypted value in the database.

**I tried:**
I converted the PII value to hashbyte (SHA2_256) but I did not get the actual value back so it is not my solution

NOTE: I am using ADF V2

In advance, thank you for your time. Any of your input will be valuable to me

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple types ways to handle pii in Azure SQL database like encryption or dynamic data masking.
Is there any specific requirement why you want to encrypt the data through ADF?
You can use dataflows within ADF to do the necessy encryption or needed

Comment: Thanks for your time.
My purpose is to add encryption in copy data activity to avoid an additional step in ADF.
I did SHA2_256 in dataflow but couldn't see any option for encryption. Any input, how do I get it?